# GO encoding/decoding

Tags: go, decode, encode

I'm workin with python. But now, I need to fix Go bug.
I have string like:

```
<!-- \\xd0\\xbf\\xd0\\xbb\\xd0\\xb0\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb6\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb9-->\\n    \\n    \\n        <guarantees>\\n
```

How do make it correct and readable?
If it were a Python, I would use `decode('unicode-escape')`. But what should I use in Go?

**Update**

I've edited description. There are double backslashes

**Update 1**

I followed the advice from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172057/11029221, and repaired the part of the code that is doing the encoding in such a wrong way.
But I found out that in GO you can fix such text like this:

```
a := `\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb6\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xb9-->\\n\\n\\n<guarantees>\\n`
a = strconv.Quote(a)
a = strings.ReplaceAll(a, `\\\\`, `\`)

unquoted, err := strconv.Unquote(a)
if err != nil {
    println(err)
}

str := []byte(unquoted)

for len(str) > 0 {
    r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRune(str)
    out = string(r) + out
    str = str[:len(str)-size]
}
fmt.Printf("%s", out)
```

Comment: Possible duplocate of [Convert unicode code point to literal character in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126749/convert-unicode-code-point-to-literal-character-in-go/34127730?r=SearchResults#34127730)

Comment: Or [How to transform Go string literal code to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303559/how-to-transform-go-string-literal-code-to-its-value/49304209#49304209)

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASCII encoding for string in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287230/ascii-encoding-for-string-in-go)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what @melpomene's criteria for "knowing what they are doing" are, but the following solution has worked previously, for example for decoding broken Hebrew text:

```
("\\u00c3\\u00a4"
  .encode('latin-1')
  .decode('unicode_escape')
  .encode('latin-1')
  .decode('utf-8')
)
```

outputs

```
'ä'
```

This works as follows:

```
The string that contains only ascii-characters '\', 'u', '0', '0', 'c', etc. is converted to bytes using some not-too-crazy 8-bit encoding (doesn't really matter which one, as long as it treats ASCII characters properly)
Use a decoder that interprets the '\u00c3' escapes as unicode code point U+00C3 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE, 'Ã'). From the point of view of your code, it's nonsense, but this unicode code point has the right byte representation when again encoded with ISO-8859-1/'latin-1', so...
encode it again with 'latin-1'
Decode it "properly" this time, as UTF-8
```

Again, same remark as in the linked post: before investing too much energy trying to repair the broken text, you might want to try to repair the part of the code that is doing the encoding in such a strange way.